# Docs for Azure Node SDK (not command line)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-node-sdk

I have an app that' already integrated wit hthe AWS SDK, and am investigating whether it could support Azure.

I've deployed some test sites with the [Azure command line tools](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/#WebSites) which (on Mac and Linux) are Node based, and I've seen the [Azure SDK for Node](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node) but I was wondering if there's JavaScript (not command line) level documentation for the SDK.

Or, in short: where can I find docs on how to do (for example):

```
azure site create
```

In JavaScript?

I know I could inspect what the command line tools do, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for: http://dl.windowsazure.com/nodedocs?

Comment: Thanks. it looks like https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node README.md is based on these documents, but out of date. The URL above is maintained, and includes 'WebsiteManagementService' which is the Windows Azure Web Sites product.